# Why isn't my property doing the check?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, setter

My constructor get info from the form. The 'name' is addressed with 'aName' (from the constructor), then there has to be a check done with prop 'NameCheck'. but if I compile it, it return an empty string. Any ideas?

Code:

**---- Class ----**

```
//Fields
private List<Create> Characters;
private string name;
private int health;
private int mSpeed;
private Role role;
private Speciality speciality;

//Properties
public string NameCheck
{
    get {
        return name;
    }
    set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            name = "Name not specified";
        }
        else 
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
}

//Constructor

public Create(string aName, int aHealth, int aMSpeed, Role aRole, Speciality aSpeciality)
{
    this.name = aName;
    this.health = aHealth;
    this.mSpeed = aMSpeed;
    this.role = aRole;
    this.speciality = aSpeciality;

    Characters = new List<Create>();
}
```

**---- Form ----**

```
Create character = new Create(tbName.Text, health, mspeed, aLane, aSpecial);

Characters.Add(character);

cbSummary.Items.Add(character.ToString());
```

PS: cbSummary is a combobox.

**EDIT:**

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "Name: " + NameCheck + " - Health: "  + health + " -  MovementSpeed: " + mSpeed + " - Role: " + role + " - Speciality: " + speciality;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `this.NameCheck` instead of `this.name` in your constructor

```
public Create(string aName, int aHealth, int aMSpeed, Role aRole, Speciality aSpeciality)
{
    this.NameCheck = aName;
```

also you should check `value` for emptiness or being null instead of `name` in your property setter

```
set
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
```

Comment: ahhhh right!!! I've been redirecting it from Constructor -> Field -> Property while it doesn't even need that.. I can automatically set it from the constructor to the property! 

Many thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

You have a small typo in your property:

```
public string NameCheck
{
    get {
        return name;
    }
    set
    {
        // You need to check value, not name.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            name = "Name not specified";
        }
        else 
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't it basically the same? What would be the harm if I let 'name' in it?

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor you should use your `NameCheck` property rather than the `name` field:

```
public Create(string aName, int aHealth, int aMSpeed, Role aRole, Speciality aSpeciality)
{
    this.NameCheck = aName;
    this.health = aHealth;
    this.mSpeed = aMSpeed;
    this.role = aRole;
    this.speciality = aSpeciality;

    Characters = new List<Create>();
}
```

Also as Paddy said you are doing an incorrect check in the `set` body of `NameCheck`:

```
public string NameCheck
{
    get
    {
        return name;
    }
    set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            name = "Name not specified";
        }
        else 
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed it was foolish of me to redirect it that much (without success even..). Thanks for the reply mate!